# Compiler isn't identifying entity declaration?

Tags: vhdl, hdl, intel-fpga, quartus

Does anyone know why I am receiving this error upon trying to compile?

> Error (12006): Node instance "clkd" instantiates undefined entity
>   "gen_counter"

Here's my code:

```
architecture struct of Vending_Machine_REV1 is

signal      clk_en_1Hz   :std_logic;

component gen_counter is
generic (
        wide :positive;
        max  :positive
        );
port (
        clk   :in   std_logic;
        data      :in std_logic_vector( wide-1 downto 0 );
        load      :in std_logic;
        enable  :in std_logic;
        reset     :in std_logic;
        count     :out std_logic_vector( wide-1 downto 0 );
        term      :out std_logic
        );
    end component;

begin

    LEDR(9 downto 7) <= (others => '0'); --(others => '0'),
    LEDR(2 downto 0) <= output_state;

    LEDR(6) <= clk_en_1Hz;

-- first use an instance of counter to get clock enable 
-- this takes the 50 MHz clock and produces a 1 Hz signal on it's "term" output.
clkd :gen_counter
generic map (
        wide => 28,
        max => 50000000 
        )
port map (
        clk     => CLOCK_50,
        data    => (others => '0'),
        load    => '0',
        enable  => '1',
        reset   => '0',
        count   => open,
        term    => clk_en_1Hz
        );

end;
```

Any help would be appreciated, I feel like it is a simple fix but I am stuck.

Comment: Have you included an entity and architecture description for `gen_counter`?  The synthesis tool needs that in order to implement an entire design.

Comment: If you have a gen_counter entity/architecture, then possibly (1) it isn't in the right place (on the tool's search path) (2) you haven't added it to the project (so it never gets compiled) or (3) it implements a different component (generics and ports don't match). Check and fix these.

Comment: @MortenZilmer  I'm brainless.  Thanks! easy fix